# What is the most efficient way to convert an eight digit number to a date?

Tags: date, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using ColdFusion 9.0.1 and some database that I cannot change.

I am accessing a database that stores a date as an eight digit numeric with zero decimal places like this:

```
YYYYMMDD
```

I need to be able to read the date, add and subtract days from a date, and create new dates.  I am looking for a ColdFusion solution to efficiently (not much code) to convert the date to our standard format, which is

```
MM/DD/YYYY
```

And then convert it back into the database's format for saving.

I need to code this in such a way that non-ColdFusion programmers can easily read this and use it, copy and modify it for other functions (such as adding a day to a date).  So, I am not looking for the most least amount of code, but efficient and readable code.

Can you suggest anything that would make this code block more flexible, readable, or more efficient (less code)?

```
<cfscript>

// FORMAT DB DATE FOR BROWSER
DateFromDB = "20111116";
DatedToBrowser = createBrowserDate(DateFromDB);
writeOutput(DatedToBrowser);

function createBrowserDate(ThisDate) {
    ThisYear = left(ThisDate, 4); 
    ThisMonth = mid(ThisDate, 4, 2);
    ThisDay = right(ThisDate, 2);
    NewDate = createDate(ThisYear, ThisMonth, ThisDay);
    NewDate = dateFormat(NewDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
    return NewDate;
}

// FORMAT BROWSER DATE FOR DB
DateFromBrowser = "11/16/2011";
DateToDB = createDBDate(DateFromBrowser);
writeDump(DateToDB);

function createDBDate(ThisDate) {
    ThisYear = year(ThisDate); 
    ThisMonth = month(ThisDate);
    ThisDay = day(ThisDate);
    NewDate = "#ThisYear##ThisMonth##ThisDay#";
    return NewDate;
}

</cfscript>
```

Comment: I think it is quite readable right now, just don't forget to Var the variables in those function.

Comment: Being nit-picky here... I would change NewDate = "#ThisYear##ThisMonth##ThisDay#"; to NewDate = ThisYear&ThisMonth&ThisDay but, I hate extraneous hash tags in my code. Also, you might be able to get rid of the createdate() and dateFormat() in the 1st function and simply return thisMonth & "/" & Thisday & "/" & ThisYear;

Comment: Actually...looking at this again, you could change createDBDate to simply return dateFormat( ThisDate, "YYYYMMDD")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually rewrite each function into 1 line of code.

```
function createBrowserDate(ThisDate) {
  return mid(ThisDate,4,2) & "/" & right(ThisDate,2) & "/" & left(ThisDate,4);
}
```

and

```
function createDBDate(ThisDate) {
  return dateFormat( ThisDate, "YYYYMMDD" );
}
```

Comment: I think you may have condensed it a bit much for my purposes, but it's certainly the most readable with the least amount of code. Thanks!

Comment: This may have the least code, but without `createDate()` you're skipping the validation.  Secondly, `ThisDate` means two different things here, since the 1st one expects YYYYMMDD and 2nd one expects a Date object.  Lastly, you can't really use CF built-in date functions with only these two functions.

Comment: First, even with the createDate() there is no 'validation' if the value passed to createBrowserDate() was not a valid date, createDate() would throw an error. Second, why would it matter if 'ThisDate' is the name of an argument in 2 different functions? Last, why can't you use any of the built in date functions?

Answer (score 7):

First find who ever did the database and kick them in the nads...

Personally I'd Convert with sql so my code only dealt with date objects.

```
Select Convert(DateTime, Convert(VarChar(8),DateTimeInventedByIdjitColumn))
From SomeTable
```

As stated by our peers, store dates as dates.

'08/06/2011' could be 8th of june of the 6th of August depending on locale.

20111643 is a valid integer..

Not using a proper date type is just a massive collection of features and bugs that at best are waiting to happen.

Comment: good point! although that's not what the question is asking for.  And since the DB date format is `YYYYMMDD`, it is at least sortable and `YYYYDDMM` is rarely use elsewhere so it's not as easy to be mistaken.

Comment: If you're _forced_ to use a string format for dates, YYYYMMDD is the best one to use, but that doesn't mean dates should be stored as strings.

Comment: Converting during the SQL stage is definitely a good idea, and makes more sense than doing it with a CFML function, though I think the example code here assumes MS SQL Server?  It's important to note this since different platforms have different conversion functions, and we don't know which one the OP is using.

Comment: Wrist firmly slapped on the sql syntax, I shall mention which one I'm using from now on. We tend to use YYYY-MM-DD, which is equally universal. Couldn't use an int, not future proof when it overflows (grin)

Comment: Peter, you made an excellent point. The reason I am requesting a ColdFusion solution is because I don't know the database that is being used. In fact, the other developers don't even know. It's kind of a big mystery. My job is to create ColdFusion solutions to these little problems.

Comment: "Not using a proper date type is just a massive collection of features and bugs that at best are waiting to happen." ~ that's an understatment. You wouldn't believe the hoops we are having to jump through to get our site talking to this database. There's little consistency to be found.  Thanks for the quote!

Answer (score 3):

**Don't keep dates as strings - keep dates as *dates*** and format them when you need to.

If you can't correct the database to use actual date columns (which you should if you can), then you can use these two functions to convert to/from YYYYMMDD and a date object:

```
function parseYMD( YYYYMMDD )
{
    if ( ! refind('^\d{8}$' , Arguments.YYYYMMDD ) )
        throw "Invalid Format. Expected YYYYMMDD";

    return parseDateTime
        ( Arguments.YYYYMMDD.replaceAll('(?<=^\d{4})|(?=\d{2}$)','-') );
}

function formatYMD( DateObj )
{
    return DateFormat( DateObj , 'yyyymmdd' );
}
```

By using date objects it means that any level of developer can work with them, without needing to care about formatting, via built-in functions like [DateAdd](http://cfdocs.org/dateadd), [DateCompare](http://cfdocs.org/datecompare), and so on.

Comment: I might use throw() rather than throw so I could actually throw a better exception type than just "application", but other than that I think this is the best answer here.

Comment: Peter, I really appreciate your taking the time to answer the question. However, I don't think you read my question carefully. First, I have no control over the database. I can't change it nor advise any change. Second, while your code may execute perfectly, it's a long way from readable by the "average coder" (whatever that is).  Thanks!

Comment: For the record, I specifically asked each of the people I am working with about their experience with regular expressions. None had any experience. The biggest benefit to using ColdFusion is that there are 100 solutions to any problem.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a regular expression fan since it's not that readable to me.

Since you're using CF9, I'd typed the argument and specify the returntype of the functions to be even more readable for the next person picking up your code.

First, right after I read the date from DB, I'd parse it to a Date object using `parseDBDate()`

```
Date function parseDBDate(required String dbDate)
{
    var yyyy = left(dbDate, 4); 
    var mm = mid(dbDate, 4, 2);
    var dd = right(dbDate, 2);

    return createDate(yyyy , mm, dd);
}
```

Once you have the date object, you can use all those built-in Date functoin like `DateAdd()` or `DateDiff()`.

Call `browserDateFormat()` right before you need to display it.

```
String function browserDateFormat(required Date date) 
{
    return dateFormat(date, "MM/DD/YYYY");
}
```

Call `dBDateFormat()` inside `<cfqueryparam value="">` when it's time to persist to DB

```
String function dBDateFormat(required Date date) 
{
    return dateFormat(date, "YYYYMMDD");
}
```

Comment: FWIW, my regex basically says "at the position after the first four digits, or the position before the last two digits, insert a hyphen". Regex really isn't hard to learn once you take some time to understand it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the info!  It looks like you come from a Java world. True?

Comment: Kind of. :)  Just following the CF's function naming convention with `parseXXX()` and `XXXFormat()`

Answer (score 0):

One liner :)

```
myDateString = "20110203";

myCfDate = createObject("java","java.text.SimpleDateFormat").init("yyyyMMdd").parse(myDateString,createObject("java","java.text.ParsePosition").init(0*0));
```

If you want to parse different patterns, change "yyyyMMdd" to any other supported pattern.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

The ParsePosition is used to say where to start parsing the string.
0*0 is shorthand for JavaCast("int",0) - in the Adobe cf engine, 0 is a string, until you apply math to it, then it becomes a Double, which the ParsePosition constructor supports. Technically, it constructs with an int, but cf is smart enough to downgrade a Double to an int.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/ParsePosition.html